# Are "rooting" and "unlocking" questions allowed on Android.SE?

Tags: discussion

Are "rooting" and "unlocking" questions allowed on Android.SE, or are they inappropriate?

Answer (score 8):

https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=root :)

Unlocking questions are on-topic when they're not carrier-specific like getting them to give you an unlock code -- questions need to be about Android.

Unlocking and rooting have been ruled legal when the issue has come up in the States, I believe.  I don't know about other areas but it seems there should be no reason for us to avoid them.